# How can I create a PDF file without using a library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a PDF from a JS object without using a library, my code is as follows:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob(["Random text"], {type: 'application/pdf'})
console.log(blob)
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
downloadLink.href = url;
downloadLink.download = `${title}.pdf`;

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

This actually creates a PDF object that gets downloaded, but the problem with this PDF is that it is unable to be opened by any pdf reader, which makes me feel like I am doing it the wrong way. My other alternative was to use `window.print` but it entails the user having to click the save button when the print dialog pops up. Any Idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Is this your actual code? "Random text" is not a valid PDF document. It is just text. Setting the content type does not magically create a PDF document.

Comment: @rveerd okay, please can you assist then ?

Comment: I do not think you really want to create a PDF document from binary data without using a library. If you do, you need to find a description of the binary format. I am not sure if it is publicly available. You can start on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF).

Comment: @rveerd Take a look at my answer, then :P

Answer (score 4):

A PDF document is made up of several sections:

- A one-line **header** identifying the version of the PDF specification to which thefile conforms
- A **body** containing the objects that make up the document contained in the file
- A **cross-reference table** containing information about the indirect objects in the file
- A **trailer** giving the location of the cross-reference table and of certain specialobjects within the body of the file

The following code is an actual `Hello World` PDF document from [this tutorial](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/10/make-your-own-pdf-file-part-4-hello-world-pdf/). The full guide on [Understanding the PDF File Format from Leon Atherton](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-overview/) will provide a detailed and simple answer to all of your questions.

There is also a huge [Portable Document Format reference book](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) from Adobe, if you really want to understand how it works.

The official pdf specification has been an ISO norm since 2008, ISO 32000-1; Adobe provides a copy thereof on their web site with merely the official ISO headers replaced: [PDF32000_2008.pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Meanwhile (2018) ISO has published an updated version, ISO 32000-2.

Create a `.txt` file, open it in your favourite editor, paste this code. Then, change the extension to `.pdf`. You will see a working PDF document.

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 500 800] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 44>>
stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Hello World!)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000212 00000 n
0000000250 00000 n
0000000317 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
406
%%EOF
```

Comment: I wonder why you don't include the pdf specification ISO 32000-1 / ISO 32000-2. A copy of part 1 after all has been made available for free download by Adobe...

Comment: @mkl Sorry, I pasted the wrong link before. The `Portable Document Format reference book` should be the reference you are talking about. Feel free to edit my answer if not!

Comment: The reference you linked is the pdf reference 1.4. The much newer pdf reference 1.7 served as the base for ISO 32000-1, the first actual specification of pdf. I added a paragraph to that effect to your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer made me realize that I actually _do_ want to use a library.

Answer (score -7):

```
function genPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20,20,'TEST Message!!');
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(20,20,'TEST Page 2!');
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
// decides your pdf layout
```

Download PDF

Comment: OP clearly stated "without using a library", while this code is using a library and you do not even mention it.